# What is -o flag in yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

I am getting through Nuxt installation guide and starting the app is done with this command:

```
yarn dev -o
```

What is the `-o`?

Comment: What's the dev command? `-o` goes to that, not to Yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yarn dev -o` is actually related to the commands in the `scripts` in `package.json`. To be more specific it's related to this line: `"dev": "nuxt dev"`. Exploring Nuxt documentation on commands there is this option `--open, -o`, which means `Open URL in browser`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [yarn run](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/) page:

> yarn run test -o --watch

> Running this command will execute jest -o --watch

From the [yest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli)

> Run tests related to changed files based on hg/git (uncommitted files):

> jest -o

So looks like it runs test against the changed files in your workspace not against the commited files in your repository